# how to implement jQuery .get()

Tags: jquery

I've two unordered lists

```
<ul id="proItems">                    
        <li class="item swipe"><img src="gallery/one.jpg" /></li>
        <li class="item swipe"><img src="gallery/two.jpg" /></li>
        <li class="item swipe"><img src="gallery/three.jpg" /></li>
        <li class="item swipe"><img src="gallery/four.jpg" /></li>
        <li class="item swipe"><img src="gallery/five.jpg" /></li>
        <li class="item swipe"><img src="gallery/six.jpg" /></li>
</ul>  
<ul id="indicator">                    
         <li class="indicate"></li>
         <li class="indicate"></li>
         <li class="indicate"></li>
         <li class="indicate"></li>
         <li class="indicate"></li>
         <li class="indicate"></li>
</ul>
```

Everytime, when I click on any item on `ul#proItems`, the css of the corresponding `ul#indicator` item will be changed. For example, if I clicked on the **2nd element** on the `ul#proItems`, the **2nd item** of `ul#indicator` will be affected.

I've my jquery codes identifying the index of the li item being clicked on `ul#proItems`, and I did something like (click event being applied on the `ul#proItems li`)

```
var index = $(this).index();
$("#indicator li.indicate").get(index).css('background-color', '#111');
```

This doesn't seem to be working. What do I need to change to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns a DOM Element, not a jQuery object.

You should use [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead:

```
var index = $(this).index();
$("#indicator li.indicate").eq(index).css('background-color', '#111');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working demo of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/f6Xth/7/.

```
$('ul#proItems li').click(function() {
    $('#indicator li').eq($('ul#proItems li').index(this)).css('color', 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = $(this).index();
$("#indicator :nth-child(" + (index + 1) + ")").css('background-color', '#111');
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#indicator li.indicate:eq(" + index+ ")")
```